# Using torify with another browser?

Tags: torsocks, browsers, torify

How do you use torify with another browser through a bridge? (because tor is blocked by the ISP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use bridges with the tor daemon, simply write on your torrc:

```
UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
```

and then the different lines of bridges, the whole line. One bridge per line.:

```
Bridge obfs4 ip fingerprint etc
```

Once you have updated your torrc file, restart the tor daemon and you should be able to use torify/torsocks with the bridge. Answer lovingly stolen from [here](https://forum.torproject.net/t/tor-blocked-in-russia-how-to-circumvent-censorship/982/5).